# Вызвать метод без повторного ввода данных

Tags: java

У меня есть два класса, main и Lesson7. В классе Lesson7 у меня есть три метода:

> input()

- возвращает ввод с консоли(переменная scr),

> pullingUp

- возвращает переменную (valueInWork)

> pullingUpForTwenty

- ничего не возвращает.

Если я буду вызывать с main поочередно программу, например

> lesson7.pullingUpForTwenty(lesson7.pullingUp(lesson7.input()),lesson7.input());

то программа два раза зайдет в метод input(), и соответственно мне нужно два раза вводить параметры, глобальными их сделать не вариант.
Заранее спасибо.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Lesson7 {

```
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private int onePullingUp = 5;
private int rest = 60;



public  int input() {

    System.out.println("Введите количество подходов");
    int scr = scanner.nextInt();
    return scr;


}

public int pullingUp(int scr) {
    int value = scr * (scr + 1) / 2;
    System.out.println("Кол-во подтягиваний: " + value);

    int valueInWork = value * onePullingUp;
    int valueInRest = scr * rest;
    int valueAll = valueInWork + valueInRest - 60;

    System.out.println("Количество времени выполнения: " + valueAll / 60 + " минуты " + valueAll % 60 + " секунд");
    return valueInWork;

}

public void pullingUpForTwenty(int valueInWork,int scr) {
    double restForTwenty = 60;
    for (int i = 1; i < scr - 1; i++) {
        double scrForTwenty = restForTwenty * 0.2;
        restForTwenty += restForTwenty;
        restForTwenty = scrForTwenty + restForTwenty;

    }
    if (scr > 1) {
        int valueAll2 = (int) (restForTwenty + valueInWork);
        System.out.println("Количество времени выполнения с учетом добавления 20%: " + valueAll2 / 60 + " минуты " + valueAll2 % 60 + " секунд");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Количество времени выполнения: " + 0);
    }

}
```

}

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lesson7 lesson7 = new Lesson7();
    lesson7.pullingUpForTwenty(lesson7.pullingUp(lesson7.input()),lesson7.input());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Lesson7 lesson7 = new Lesson7();
  int inp = lesson7.input();
  lesson7.pullingUpForTwenty(lesson7.pullingUp(inp), inp);
}
```

или

```
public class Lesson7 {
  ...

  int _input;
  boolean _hasInput = false;

  public  int input() {
    if (!_hasInput) {
      System.out.println("Введите количество подходов");
      _input = scanner.nextInt();
      _hasInput = true;
    }
    return _input;
  }
```